# Unit testing a simple javascript function used in my React app with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using Cypress to test my React application. So far, I love it, but I'd like to unit test some basic functions, including this `range` function:

```
const range = (start, end) => {
  const ans = [];
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    ans.push(i);
  }
  return ans;
};
```

I've tried importing the function into a `cypress/integration/helpers.spec.js` but it doesn't work:

```
import { range } from 'utils/helpers';

context('Helpers', () => {
  it('range', () => {
    expect(range(3).toLocaleString.equal([0, 1, 2]));
    expect(range(1, 3).toLocaleString.equal([1, 2]));
  });
});
```

Cypress throws the following error:

> Cannot find module 'utils/helpers'

Any tips for importing a functions into Cypress? Is Cypress even the correct choice for testing this simple function or should I use a different testing framework? I'd prefer to use Cypress if possible so I can use a single testing framework.

Comment: Try adjusting the import path, something like `import { range } from '../src/utils/helpers';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Module import/export

You forgot about the `export`. In a module that you want to `import` elsewhere, you specify `export` or `export default` if you have only one module. In your case:

```
export default const range = (start, end) => {
  const ans = [];
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    ans.push(i);
  }
  return ans;
};
```

or

```
const range = (start, end) => {
  const ans = [];
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    ans.push(i);
  }
  return ans;
};

export default range;
```

Also, the paths are set relative to the current file, those `helpers.spec.js`. In your case, it should probably be like this: `../support/utils/helpers`.

#### Unit and integration tests in Cypress

Regarding unit tests, there is often an opinion that it is worth paying more attention to the implementation of integration tests, since they allow you to comprehensively check many functions and the interaction between them, while unit tests are aimed at checking only one function.

Here's more about unit and integration tests:

- [YouTube video that explains the types of testing and when to apply it.](https://youtu.be/-2zP494wdUY)
- [A short text version of the video above. It also describes general
  testing practices in JavaScript.](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/javascript-testing-best-practices#-%EF%B8%8F21-enrich-your-testing-portfolio-look-beyond-unit-tests-and-the-pyramid)
- [The official guide to the Cypress when to write unit tests.](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/general-questions-faq.html#So-what-benefits-would-one-get-for-converting-one%E2%80%99s-unit-tests-from-Karma-or-Jest-to-Cypress)

Additional:

- [Examples of implementing unit tests from the official Cypress website.](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html#Unit-Testing.)
- [Useful library for unit tests.](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test)